# Как скомпоновать программу в Cygwin для cigwin.dll?

Tags: mingw, cygwin

Windows 7, Cygwin
Во всех руководствах пишут, что разница между Cygwin и MinGW в том, что программы, скомпонованные в среде Cygwin  должны распространяться с dll, в отличие от MinGW, которая компонует программу сразу под WIndows. Но у меня не получается так. Компонуя helloworld на Си у меня в exe файле нет зависимости от sygwin.dll. (Проверено Dependensy Walker.) Получившийся екзешник запускается на чужом компьютере без dll. В объектном файле написано: **GCC: (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0**. Если же компилировать в окне mingw64 то в объектном файле будет запись **GCC: (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1**
Может cygwin нужно как-то специально настраивать, что бы не через MSYS2 собирал, а для своей dll?

Comment: поправил, спасибо

Comment: 1. cigwin.dll, sygwin.dll, или всё-таки cygwin.dll? 2. и всё-таки стоит указать ссылку хотя бы на одно руководство, про которое вы пишете.

Comment: Хотя бы вот: Когда вы распространяете свое программное обеспечение, получатель должен будет запустить его вместе со средой выполнения Cygwin (предоставленной файлом cygwin1.dll).https://ask-dev.ru/info/4728/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw Тоже самое написано везде... "при компиляции программы с помощью Cygwin, по условиям его лицензии вы будете линковаться с его динамической библиотекой cygwin1.dll и таскать её всюду за собой, в то время, как с MinGW, вы будете зависеть только от стандартных MSVC библиотек"

Answer (score 0):

Возможно на этапе очистки библиотека отпала так как не вызывались функции из неё?

Возможно переменные окружения от mingw попали в среду сборки cygwin и линковщик настроился по-мингвшному.

Comment: Вот если бы ещё знать, какие переменные там должны быть. В %PATH есть только пути к MinGW.  Добавление в $PATH пути к cygwin\bin не помогло.

Comment: при этом пути от мингв из PATH убрали?

Comment: Спасибо. Всё переустановил и заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло полное удаление Cygwin и MinGW и установка всего по новой. Теперь всё работает правильно, Dependency Walker теперь видит и ругается на непонятную cygwin1.dll